# Confusion over definition of attractor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The definition of attractor says that "A compact invariant set $M$ will be called an attractor if it has an open neighbourhood $O$ such that every trajectory in $O$ remains in $O$ and converges to $M$. What is the intuitive meaning of it ? How is it related to limit set and invariant set (for which intuitive meaning is clear).

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, an attractor is a trap. Every trajectory that steps into $O$ cannot escape: on the opposite, it is drawn toward $M$ and eaten there.

> How is it related to ... invariant set

By definition, every attractor is an invariant set. The converse is false: e.g., a repelling periodic orbit is an invariant set (also a limit set) but is not an attractor.

> How is it related to limit set

An attractor contains the limit set of every trajectory. But it can be larger than any limit set it contains: for example, it can be a cylinder in 3D that attracts orbits, whereas the limit set of every orbit might be just a horizontal section of this cylinder.